# File name causing syntax error "Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Syntax error"

Tags: syntax, vbscript

I have been trying to figure out what could be wrong with my statement. I'm getting a syntax error in my `Elseif` row 10.
I accidently found the error being caused by the name of the file `TURN5_855.vbs`. I change the file name for any other combination or name as long as it is not `TURN5_855.vbs`. Can some one help me understand why?
I tried all the below, and any will help solve the syntax error:

- `TURN_855.vbs`
- `SCRIPT5_855.vbs`
- `5_855.vbs`
- `855.vbs`
- `TURNS_855.vbs`

I feel like I can use any combination except `TURN5_855.vbs`

```vb
Function ACK()
    EDI.iValue("ACKQty") = EDI.Element(2)
    If EDI.Element(1) = "IA" Then
            If EDI.iValue("PO1Qty") <> EDI.iValue("ACKQty") Then
                EDI.Element(1) = "IQ"
                EDI.MessageLocation = EDI.EndOfProcessing       
                EDI.MessageSeverity = EDI.Report
                EDI.Message = "-Item " & EDI.Value("MyStockCode") & " EDI 850 Qty was " & EDI.Value("PO1Qty") & ".  Our but quantity " & EDI.Value("ACKQty") & " was confirmed, possible due to backorders."
            ' Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Syntax error
            Elseif EDI.Value("IPFlag") = "ON" Then
                EDI.Element(1) = "IP"
                EDI.MessageLocation = EDI.EndOfProcessing       
                EDI.MessageSeverity = EDI.Report
                EDI.Message = "-Item " & EDI.Value("MyStockCode") & " EDI 850 Price was " & EDI.Value("850Price") & ".  Our price is " & EDI.Value("OurPrice") & "."
            else
                EDI.Element(1) = "IA"
                EDI.MessageLocation = EDI.EndOfProcessing       
                EDI.MessageSeverity = EDI.Report
                EDI.Message = "-Item " & EDI.Value("MyStockCode") & " is confirmed."
            End if
    Elseif EDI.Element(1) = "IR" Then  
        EDI.MessageLocation = EDI.EndOfProcessing       
        EDI.MessageSeverity = EDI.Report
        EDI.Message = "-Item " & EDI.Value("MyStockCode") & " or Order " & EDI.sValue("PurchaseOrder") & " was rejected."
    End if
End function
```

Comment: I can't see anything syntactically wrong with this code. Usually, a `Function` should have a `FunctionName = ReturnValue` as functions should return something or they are in effect a `Sub` procedure, but none of that will cause a "syntax error".

Comment: Okay, I just found out that the actual name of the file is what is triggering the syntax error... but I can't understand the why. I will change this post as I need to know why.